# Acquiring an oAuth access token from an external service

Tags: oauth

I'm really new to Apex and coding in general, so I seem to get stuck while trying to retrieve an access token.
I still can't quite figure out the logic between how to send the request and how to retrieve the access token and how to make it all work.

```java
    public with sharing class CleverreachTest {
    String username = 'myuser';
    String password = 'mypw'; 
    String accesstoken;
    String instanceURL;
    String clientID = 'myclientid' ;
    string clientSecret = 'mysecret';

    public CleverreachTest(string username, string pwd, string clientId, string clientsecret)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = pwd;
        this.clientId = clientId;
        this.clientSecret = clientSecret;
    }
    public void startAuth(){
        //Get the token
        Http httpCls = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('https://rest.cleverreach.com/oauth/authorize.php');
        request.setMethod('GET');
        request.setTimeout(2 * 60 * 1000);

        request.setHeader('Token', 'https://rest.cleverreach.com/oauth/token.php');
        request.setBody('grand_type=password' + 
                       '&client_id=' + clientId +
                       '&client_secret=' + clientSecret + 
                       '&username=' + username +
                       '&password=' + password);

        httpResponse response = httpCls.send(request);

        if(response.getStatusCode() == 200){
            system.debug('## Succesfully retrieving access token');
            map<string,Object> resultMap = (map<string,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
            accesstoken = (String)resultMap.get('access_token');
            instanceURL = (String)resultMap.get('instance_url');

        }

        else{
            system.debug('## Could not retrieve the access token');
            system.debug('## response status:' + response.getStatus());
            system.debug('## response message:' + response.getBody());
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: I'd suggest making an [edit] to your question and providing what exactly doesn't work. For example, what values are getting assigned to `accesstoken` or are there errors running the code? You can also add in `System.debug` statements in your if condition and let us know what the values are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do the Oauth authentication in a named credetial (outside of apex) and then simply reference the named credential in apex

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=named_credentials_about.htm&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5

That'll greatly simplify your code.

Comment: Oh wow! All along I was searching for a solution that used Apex but this is much simpler. Thanks!

Comment: Enjoy, don't forget to mark the answer!